# Problems appending columns from one excel file to another

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, openpyxl

I seem to be unable to figure out how to append values from one excel file to another one.
I have tried append mode numerous times but it fails each time due to encoding errors.
I have sought solutions but none has turned out to solve my problem.

I have two excel files which have a certain amount of rows. They have the same columns. I would like to append the rows from one file to the other.

```css
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("WindSpeed.xlsx",sheet_name=0 ,index_col=None)
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
df['WindDirection']
df=df[df['WindDirection'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '.').astype(int) >= 315]
df.to_excel('WindDirectionNorth.xlsx')

df = pd.read_excel("WindSpeed.xlsx",sheet_name=0 ,index_col=None)
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
df['WindDirection']
df=df[df['WindDirection'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '.').astype(int) <= 45]
df.to_excel('WindDirectionNorth2.xlsx')


f1 = open('WindDirectionNorth.xlsx', 'a+', encoding='utf8')
f2 = open('WindDirectionNorth2.xlsx', 'r', encoding='utf8')

f1.write(f2.read())
f1.seek(0)
f2.seek(0)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

This code brings me back the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 14: invalid start byte

If I out (rb) instead of (r) it returns the following error: ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error may suggest that file doesn't use `utf-8` but different encoding.

Comment: you can't work with excel files using standard `open()`. Excel may have data as XML file compressed as ZIP and you can't append one zip file to another zip file - you have to use special modules for this - they have to uncompress data, convert data to Python structure, move element from one structure to another and later convert back to XML, and compress back to zip file. You should do all in `pandas.DataFrame`. BTW: only `csv` file can be used with standard `open()` because `csv` is `plain-text` - but it still would need to skip header from second file.

Comment: I think you could select all rows at once using `df[ (... >= 315) or (... <= 45) ]`

Comment: When applying your contribute to only my first 6 lines of code I receive the following error:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'ellipsis' and 'int'
Though, I have found a solution to my problem after another 2 hours intensive search and tries. I would still be open to other suggestions if you could provide it :)

Comment: I used `...` to skip some part of code and to show only more important elements - but you have to put your code in place of `...`

Comment: and small correction - it has to be `|` instead of `or` - `df[ (... >= 315) | (... <= 45) ]`

Answer (score 0):

File `.xlsx` has complex structure. It is `zip` file with many files. One of them is `.xml` with all data, others can be images embeded in file, macros in VBA, etc.

You can even change extension from `.xlsx` to `.zip` and see content.

So you can't work with Excel files using standard `open()`. You can't append one `zip` file to another `zip` file. You have to use special modules for this. They have to uncompress data, convert `XML` data to Python structure (ie. `DataFrame`), move elements from one structure to another structure and later they have to convert data back to `XML` data, and compress back to `zip` file.

You should do all in `pandas.DataFrame`.

**BTW:** `csv` file can be used with standard `open()` because `csv` is `plain-text` - but it still would need to skip header from second file.

---

In your situation I think you could select all rows using operator `|` (for `or`)

```
df[ (... >= 315) | (... <= 45) ]
```

So full code could be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("WindSpeed.xlsx", sheet_name=0, index_col=None)
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed', case=False)], axis=1, inplace=True)

values = df['WindDirection'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '.').astype(int)
df = df[ (values >= 315) | (values <= 45) ]

df.to_excel('WindDirectionNorth.xlsx')
```

Eventually you could try to use `.append()`

```
a = df[ ... >= 315 ]
b = df[ ... <= 45 ]

c = a.append(b)

c.to_excel(...)
```

---

Using `df[ (... >= 315) | (... <= 45) ]` you get rows with the same order as in original `df`.

Using `c = a.append(b)` you get rows in different order - first rows with `>= 315` and next rows with `<= 45`